# Can't find stylesheet to import error when generating a css file for a custom theme for Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have a need to generate css file for a custom theme for Angular Material v14.x. I was able to do this with Angular material v12 before. With v14.x, when I run "sass theme.scss theme-custom-mat.css" I am getting this error.

`Error: Can't find stylesheet to import. ╷ 1 │ @use '@angular/cdk'; │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ╵ node_modules\@angular\material\core\style\_menu-common.scss 1:1  @forward node_modules\@angular\material\_index.scss 33:1                  @use mat-lt2.scss 1:1                                                 @import theme.scss 2:9                                                   root stylesheet`

@angular/cdk is installed. I understand that I can update the path relative to node_modules folder to fix it, but there are few other files that are throwing similar errors. How do I fix it without modifying each of those files? I read to use stylePreprocessorOptions to include node_modules in the includePaths, without any luck. This might be due to using sass directly to build css rather than as part of angular build. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Duh. Need to include --load-path=node_modules

```
sass theme.scss theme-custom-mat.css --load-path=node_modules
```